# Is there a 64 bit version of SSMS and BIDS with SQL Server 2008 64 bit?

Tags: sql-server-2008, 64-bit

Yesterday we had a very heated discussion at work regarding the availability of a 64 bit version of SSMS and BIDS with SQL Server 2008 64 bit.

While I know for sure that such a thing does not exist for SQL 2005, I could neither convince nor prove that this does not exist for SQL Server 2008 64 bit. The lead developer who claims that this exists even went to the extent of saying that with SQL 2008 64 bit, you can actually double click on an SSIS package and edit it within SSMS. I suspect the developer is referring to a maintenance plan.

Since we ran out of time, the discussion will continue today. I have searched the internet and Microsoft, but I am unable to find much documentation on this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Raj

Answer (score 3):

1) Is SQL Server Management Studio shipped with SQL Server 2008 64 bit , also 64 bit?

Ans: SQL Server Management Studio is a 32 bit application Runtime Compatibility SQL Server Management Studio 2008 runs in WOW64 mode on 64-bit clients. Because of this, the 32-bit version of SQL Server Compact must be installed to use the tools available within SQL Server Management Studio http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835497.aspx

2) Is it possible to directly edit deployed SSIS packages from within Management Studio?

Ans: Currently you cannot load a package from Mgt studio for editing. From Mgt studio you can see what’s running, what’s stored, and can execute a package but not edit. Ref: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/9cc6a819-e7b5-40a2-b5b6-0957118ffed7/

3) Is there a 64 bit version of Business Intelligence Development Studio?

Ans: Business Intelligence Development Studio, the 32-bit development environment for Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services projects, is not designed to run on the Itanium 64-bit architecture and is not installed on Itanium servers. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe this page may contain the answers to your debate: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141766.aspx (SQL Server 2008 Books Online (June 2009)64-bit Considerations for Integration Services). A quick look at that page would seem to indicate that the BIDS and SSMS environments are still 32-bit.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had already looked up this link and it does not categorically state that SSMS and BIDS are available only in 32 bit. I have contacted M$ and hope to hear from them soon.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 64-bit version of BIDS or SSMS in SQL Server 2008.  This is because both tools are extensions to the Visual Studio IDE and there is no 64-bit version of the Visual Studio IDE.  They both run fine on the WOW64 subsystem on x64 Windows operating systems.  I believe only SSMS is supported on WOW64 subsystem of ia64 Windows operating systems.